# Does the compiler optimize non-polymorphic calls to virtual methods?

Tags: c++, optimization, polymorphism, virtual, inline

Does the compiler optimize/inline non-polymorphic calls to virtual methods? I mean when the call is in a non-polymorphic context so everything is known at compile time?

Comment: Yes, if the compiler can it will for sure.

Comment: It's called devirtualization, and yes, it sometimes happens (though it has limits).

Answer (score 0):

> Does the compiler optimize/inline non-polymorphic calls to virtual methods?

Yes, every decent compiler would do this.

GCC and MSVC do it even on `-O0`/`/Od` modes.

## [LIVE DEMO](http://tinyurl.com/ps9xbng)

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
    #define NOINLINE __declspec(noinline)
#else
    #define NOINLINE __attribute__ ((noinline))
#endif

template<int>
NOINLINE void ASM_MARKER()
{
    static volatile int anti_opti = 11;
    (void)anti_opti;
}

void base();
void derived();

struct Base
{
    virtual void foo()
    {
        base();
    }
};
struct Derived: Base
{
    void foo() override
    {
        derived();
    }
};

int main()
{
    ASM_MARKER<1000>();
    Base b;
    b.foo();
    ASM_MARKER<2000>();
    Derived d;
    d.foo();
    ASM_MARKER<3000>();
    Base &r = d;
    r.foo();
    ASM_MARKER<4000>();
}
```

G++ 4.8  -O0:

```
    call    void ASM_MARKER<1000>()
    movq    vtable for Base+16, -32(%rbp)
    leaq    -32(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    Base::foo()
    call    void ASM_MARKER<2000>()
    movq    vtable for Derived+16, -16(%rbp)
    leaq    -16(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    Derived::foo()
    call    void ASM_MARKER<3000>()
    leaq    -16(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, -8(%rbp)
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    movq    (%rax), %rax
    movq    (%rax), %rax
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rdx
    movq    %rdx, %rdi
    call    *%rax      // <--------------- NOT OPTIMIZED
    call    void ASM_MARKER<4000>()
```

MSVC2010SP1 /Od:

```
; Line 34
    call    ??$ASM_MARKER@$0DOI@@@YAXXZ     ; ASM_MARKER<1000>
; Line 35
    lea rcx, QWORD PTR b$[rsp]
    call    ??0Base@@QEAA@XZ
; Line 36
    lea rcx, QWORD PTR b$[rsp]
    call    ?foo@Base@@UEAAXXZ          ; Base::foo
; Line 37
    call    ??$ASM_MARKER@$0HNA@@@YAXXZ     ; ASM_MARKER<2000>
; Line 38
    lea rcx, QWORD PTR d$[rsp]
    call    ??0Derived@@QEAA@XZ
; Line 39
    lea rcx, QWORD PTR d$[rsp]
    call    ?foo@Derived@@UEAAXXZ           ; Derived::foo
; Line 40
    call    ??$ASM_MARKER@$0LLI@@@YAXXZ     ; ASM_MARKER<3000>
; Line 41
    lea rax, QWORD PTR d$[rsp]
    mov QWORD PTR r$[rsp], rax
; Line 42
    mov rax, QWORD PTR r$[rsp]
    mov rax, QWORD PTR [rax]
    mov rcx, QWORD PTR r$[rsp]
    call    QWORD PTR [rax]       // <--------------- NOT OPTIMIZED
; Line 43
    call    ??$ASM_MARKER@$0PKA@@@YAXXZ     ; ASM_MARKER<4000>
```